# Debug error "No symbols have been loaded" when removing a link

Tags: c#, debugging, linker, debug-symbols

I have a sln that includes different projects with different references between them.

I've add a small change in program.main() , removed the initiation of a class from it, and done the imitation from a different place
The line was removed from main:
//Class1 classExmple = new Class1() 
And added in a different place .

Once the new Class1() is removed and I rebuild, any breakpoint in Class1 get the error message "No symbols have been loaded" .For some reason also any breakpoint in other projects as well.
I can see the relevant dlls were built and are up do date. 
I can also see all the dlls are in the project reference list.

Would appreciate your help,
Thanks,
Dana.

Comment: Are you rebuilding it as release or debug? You need to rebuild and run it as Debug, not Release or you won't create the symbols.

Comment: this means your project is complied but your debugger not getting latest dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

1. clean solution, and rebuild
2. remove all temp or refereed file and add referances again (remove debug and obj folder )
3. make sure you are refering dll from where it placed with pdb file of it

Comment: make sure you are refering dll from where it placed with pdb file of it - This was my problem. Thanks,